# Matlab: search index of substring in cell

Tags: matlab, vector, split

I've got a cell `indix` which contains informations about date and time.

```
 '2015-03-28 16:58:50.043'
 '2015-03-28 16:58:50.054'
 '2015-03-28 16:58:50.064'
 '2015-03-28 16:58:50.075'
 '2015-03-28 16:58:50.085'
 '2015-03-28 16:58:50.095'
 '2015-03-28 16:58:50.106'
```

The user should type in i.e. `"50.064"` and should become the index of the third column. I've tried to implement this:

```
 start = find(ismember(indix,'2015-10-28 16:58:50.064'))
```

Which gives me the right result, but I'm currently looking for a possibility to get that with just typing in the above line.

Is there any way for that? Otherwise my idea was to split the vector with whitespace..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use the [`strfind`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) function to search a cell array for a partial string within each cell.

```
>> indix = {'2015-03-28 16:58:50.043', '2015-03-28 16:58:50.054', '2015-03-28 16:58:50.064'};
>> find(cellfun(@isempty, strfind(indix, '50.064')) == 0)
ans =
     3
```

[`cellfun`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) and `@isempty` returns a vector of `1`'s for the indexes where `'50.064'` was not found and `0` where it was. That's why we use [`find`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to check for equality against `0`.